# Overriding a parent class instance (non-static) method javascript

Tags: javascript, es6-class

My use case is React, but this is a JavaScript question.

I'd like to extend the functionality of `componentWillMount` by using a subclass. How can I accomplish this?

```
class Super {
    componentWillMount() {
        doStuff()
    }
}
class Sub extends Super {
    componentWillMount() {
        super() // this doesn't work
        doMoreStuff()
    }
}
```

Comment: `super.componentWillMount();` should it be ?

Comment: by `super()` your are invoking/calling the constructor of the parent ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax to use is:

```
super.componentWillMount()
```

From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super):

> The `super` keyword is used to call functions on an object's parent.
>
> The `super.prop` and `super[expr]` expressions are valid in any method definition in both classes and object literals.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> super([arguments]); // calls the parent constructor.
> super.functionOnParent([arguments]);
> ```

Demo:

```js
class Super {
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('parent')
    }
}

class Sub extends Super {
    componentWillMount() {
        super.componentWillMount()
        console.log('child')
    }
}

new Sub().componentWillMount();
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! Guess I should've read more of the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 1):

From react docs:

> So What About Inheritance?
>   At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven't found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.
>
> Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to
>   customize a component's look and behavior in an explicit and safe way.
>   Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including
>   primitive values, React elements, or functions.
>
> If you want to reuse non-UI functionality between components, we
>   suggest extracting it into a separate JavaScript module. The
>   components may import it and use that function, object, or a class,
>   without extending it.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: I'm trying to extend the functionality of a component in the react-google-maps npm library. What would you recommend?

Comment: Create a component that wraps react-google-map and adds extra features to it.

Comment: it's not that simple to override `componentWillMount` functionality without using `super.componentWillMount()` (which was the answer to my question)